# Launching ipython notebook via the api (script)

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

How can I do the equivalent of `ipython notebook` and `ipython profile` from inside a python script? It should be straightforward but I can't track down the right invocation. (Inter alia I blindly tried `IPython.start_kernel()` and `from IPython.extensions import notebook` and variants, but had no luck so far.)

In my case, I can't just launch a subprocess and execute `ipython notebook`: I'm on a weird configuration where I can run python from the Start menu (Windows 7), but not from the command line or from the script. (To be completely clear: I do know the location of the python executable, but am restricted from executing it directly).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some sleuthing and reflection, I decided the best solution is to let IPython start notebook itself. So the problem is to simulate what happens when calling ipython from the command line:

```
% ipython notebook <directory>
```

IPython is started from the command line via a short python script. **I import it but make it think it's run as the `__main__` module:**

```
import sys, imp
ipython_path = r"/path/to/ipython-script"

sys.argv = [ ipython_path, "notebook" ]
_ipython = imp.load_source('__main__', ipython_path)
```

To serve a directory different from the current directory, just add it to `sys.argv` as an additional argument:

```
sys.argv = [ ipython_path, "notebook", "path/to/notebooks" ]
```

**Where is the commandline ipython script?**
On Windows, IPython is launched with the help of `ipython_script.py` in the `Scripts` directory (e.g., `C:\Python27\Scripts\ipython_script.py`). On OS X, it can be launched by the python script `Library/Python/2.7/bin/ipython`. (I installed IPython via easy_install; I suppose there might be other configurations.) You can track down your python installation like this:

```
import IPython
import inspect
inspect.getsourcefile(IPython)
```

This is the path to the module, not the launcher script. The script will be in a nearby directory.